# Is there a (Grothendieck) $\infty$-topos for which Whitehead's theorem only holds for maps between truncated objects?

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-topos-theory

We know that non-[hypercomplete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hypercomplete+%28infinity%2C1%29-topos) $\infty$-toposes exist. Is there such a topos $\mathcal{E}$ with the following property?

> For any $X, Y \in \mathcal{E}$, if *all* weak homotopy
> equivalences (or $\infty$-connected maps) $ X \to Y$ are
> equivalences, then both $X$ and $Y$ are $n$-truncated objects for
> some $n < \infty$.

Comment: An $\infty$-connected map between $\infty$-truncated objects is an equivalence. There exist $\infty$-truncated objects that are not $n$-truncated for any finite $n$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: The identity on any object is an equivalence, so your condition implies that any object in $\mathcal E$ is truncated. Taking a product of Eilenberg-MacLane objects shows that this is not possible

Comment: @MaximeRamzi My question was very unclear. I edited it.

Comment: Zhen Lin comment still applies : if both X and Y are $\infty$-truncated objects then the result holds, and any $\infty$-topos will have $\infty$-truncated objects that are not $n$-truncated.

Comment: @SimonHenry I see. What is meant by $\infty$-truncated here?

Comment: $\infty$-connected morphisms are the map that are $n$-connected for all $n$. $\infty$-truncated morphisn are the right class of the ($\infty$-connected,$\infty$-truncated) unique factorization system. I think Lurie never use the terminology $\infty$-tuncated there, but you should get enough details from chapter 6.5 of Higher topos theory : The $\infty$-truncated objects are the objects of the Hypercompletion, and as they form an $\infty$-topos they alway contains some non $n$-truncated objects (well... unless we have a trivial topos of course).